# You have requested a non-existent service "templating.helper.form" after upgrading to 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

In one of my class I use service form helper like:

`$this->container->get('templating.helper.form');`

after upgrade from version 2.6 to 2.7, I get an exception:

> You have requested a non-existent service "templating.helper.form".

I read the upgrade guide but found nothing related to this. I Run `container:debug` as well but not contains that service.

But all of my form works well, Anybody know why ? what is "templating.helper.form" service is replaced with ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, but you have to add `php` as a templating engine, like that:

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

See more at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14790